# deleting/replacing buckets in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, bucket

Full disclosure, this is for a boot camp, but I am pretty sure my code is correct and I have reached out several times to the admins for guidance but haven't gotten a response. I keep getting an error where it says `(Bucket=bucket['Name'])`..some error about the preset. I thought maybe I should replace Bucket with Prefix but it doesn't seem to be the case.

The idea here is to delete `gim` buckets and add the `gid` buckets in its place.

```
# Get the list_buckets response
response = s3.list_buckets()

# Delete all the buckets with 'gim', create replacements.
for bucket in response['Buckets']:
  if 'gim' in bucket['Name']:
      s3.delete_bucket(Bucket=bucket['Name'])

s3.create_bucket(Bucket='gid-staging')
s3.create_bucket(Bucket='gid-processed')

# Print bucket listing after deletion
response = s3.list_buckets()
for bucket in response['Bucket']:
    print(bucket['Name'])
```

Comment: "some error about the preset" isn't enough information. Please provide the actual error message

Comment: I'd be very cautious emptying and deleting buckets based on a broad test such as `if 'gim' in bucket['Name']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going off of what alex067 said, you can remove all objects and then delete the bucket like this:

```
for bucket in response['Buckets']:
  if 'gim' in bucket['Name']:
    bucket_resource = s3.Bucket(bucket['Name'])
    bucket_resource.objects.all().delete()
    res = bucket_resource.delete()
```

I would recommend setting this up to be able to run in a "dry" mode so as not to delete any unnecessary resources if something were to go wrong. Here's how that could work:

```
for bucket in response['Buckets']:
  if 'gim' in bucket['Name']:
    bucket_resource = s3.Bucket(bucket['Name'])
    print(bucket_resource.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for bucket in response['Buckets']:
  if 'gim' in bucket['Name']:
      res = bucket.delete()
```

The bucket does have to be empty before you can delete it though.

Comment: I don't think that will work. The `bucket` variable will be a string, not a Bucket object. The code is using the S3 client, not the S3 resource.